# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, popup

I have a popup in my page which I am trying to show on dropdownlist selected index changed event.
Here is register statement

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(),"id", "ShowApplicationPopUp()",true);
```

Here is my javascript function

```
function ShowApplicationPopUp() {

    $('#NewCustomerMask').show("slow");
    $('#NewCustomerApplicationPopUp').show("slow");

}
```

Both of my divs are initially hidden by using `display:none;` statement.
The problem is when my dropdownlist is changed the popup is not seen at all.I tried putting an alert statement to check if the function is called , and the alert statement is fired.Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` the Javascript code is inserted early in the page, so it will run before the elements are loaded.

Use `RegisterStartupScript` instead, which places the code at the end of the form.

Comment: ,thanks a lot it worked ,could you just explain me the statement , I am using it for the first time.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I too could not get this code to work but thanks to the above I now have working code. Note, I have a linkbutton inside an Ajax Update Panel.

in my code behind aspx.cs page is:

```
protected void OpenButton_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    // open new window
    string httpLink = "../newWindow.aspx";      
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "openWindow('" + httpLink + "');", true);
}
```

in my apsx page is first the link to jQuery source, then second the JavaScript for the openWindow function:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(url) {
        var w = window.open(url, '', 'width=1000,height=1000,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
        w.focus();
    }
</script>
```

and the link that makes it all happen:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Open New Window" ID="LnkBtn" OnClick="OpenButton_Click" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" BorderStyle="None"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Im not a jQuery expert and must attribute some of this to the following blog:

https://blog.yaplex.com/asp-net/open-new-window-from-code-behind-in-asp-net/