# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working with DetailsView_ItemInserting

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, entitydatasource, registerclientscriptblock

I have a detailsview binded to a ClientEntitydatasource. In DetailsView_ItemInserting i'm trying to check whether user has inserted all the fields and show popup according to that.

**PROBLEM**

I have found out that if detailsview is **binded** to a datasource following would not execute:

```
 protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Values["Name"] == null)
        {
            string script = "alert('Please Insert all the mandatory Fields');";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true); //would not get execute.
        }
    }
```

In order to do that ,I have to explicitly add items to corresponding datasource and  also I have not binded it to ClentEntityDatasource in .aspx as follows:

```
 protected void DetailsView_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {


        FileUpload FileUploadControl = DetailsView.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
         if (FileUploadControl.HasFile && e.Values["Name"] != null)
        {
            string Name = e.Values["Name"].ToString();
            try
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                string MapPath = "~/Images/" + FileName;
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + FileName);
                byte[] imgdata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(MapPath));
                SqlConnection myConnection;
                string myConnectionString = "Initial Catalog=42HNetDb;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI";
                myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                string myInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Client (Name,Logo) Values(@Name,@Logo )";
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myInsertQuery);
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Logo", SqlDbType.Image);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Logo"].Value = imgdata;
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           string script = "alert('Please Insert all the mandatory Fields');";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true); //gets executed properly
        }
```

In short i have found out that if Detailsview is binded to some datasource  **ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock** would not get execute.

I have also tried using   **ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript** but nothing happens it won't give an error but no popup is shown.
Am I missing something here??If you need code.aspx just tell me.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: you debug and checked that your client script line is executing i mean your if statement becomes true

Comment: Yup it is getting executed..I have even removed the if else and tried to do it ..but no popup is shown...Actually it is getting redirected to another page which i have written in Oniteminserted Event.

Comment: you are redirected to another page from page where you write this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey please use this code

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Alert", "script", true);
```

instead of

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Hope It helps you

Comment: Can you use this one ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(DetailsView), "Alert", "script", true);

Comment: Refer This Link [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927123/clientscript-registerclientscriptblock-not-working)[Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1866521.aspx/1?DETAILSVIEW+After+the+form+details+have+been+inserted)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was going in wrong Direction , What I needed is RequiredFieldValidator for Validation controls .Refer Here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

Thanks!